# Infinite Scroll: show elements between a range

Tags: jquery, range, infinite-scroll

On my page I have 16 elements. Initially only 4 are showing and the rest 5-16 are hidden on the page. On page load I am using the :gt selector to hide everything beyond my 'post per page' number which is set to 4.

```
this.ppp    = 4;
this.count  = this.ppp - 1;
$('li.item:gt(' + this.count + ')').addClass('hide');
```

When I initiate an Infinite Scroll event, by scrolling to the bottom of the page, how can I find all the elements between the range 5-8, and then on the next event find elements between 9-12 and so on based on my posts per page value.

I tried using the .nextUntil() and :eq but using the :eq method returns an object and nextUntil() requires a string like 'li.item'.

```
this.count += this.ppp;
var eq = $("ul.items li.item").eq(this.count);
$('ul.items).nextUntil(' + eq  + ')').addClass('show');
```

Probably a better more efficient way to approach this just looking for some ideas.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the hide `items` it's better to use this:

```
$('li.item.hide:lt(' + this.ppp + ')').removeClass('hide');
```

Instead all this:

```
this.count += this.ppp;
var eq = $("ul.items li.item").eq(this.count);
$('ul.items).nextUntil(' + eq  + ')').addClass('show');
```

Check this minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/q9oh7eb9/

Comment: I actually did try that and it works to a point. The problem with using :lt less than, is it takes into account all items less than the current value of 'this.count' so my initial 4 items get animated in addition to the next set of items. That's why I specified in my question a range of items. Any ideas on how to target items within a range. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: I update my answer with this: `$('li.item.hide:lt(' + this.ppp + ')').removeClass('hide');`. How it work for you? Note that I'm selecting only the `item` elements with class `.hide`, so the first items don't should animate.

Comment: +1 Oh that's clever. I apologize I should have been more specific in my code its throwing off what I am really aiming for. If my animation is more complex or I'm not adding/removing classes but using TweenLite to animate in the items, I think I still need to select a collection of items between a range. Still trying to work through your example and see if I can use it for my actual purposes.

Comment: Good look with that, but always you can share more of your code, then we can help you much more ;)